# Connection failed for google open_id using omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, openid, ruby-1.9

I am trying to add open-id functionality to my app, I am using omniauth and omniauth-openid gems for same.

I have done the installation steps added it to initializer as middleware,

```
require 'omniauth-openid'
require 'openid/store/filesystem'

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do 
  provider :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp')
end
```

and a routes for andling callback

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'callback#myauthentication'
```

when I try to hit this url, to connect to **google provider**

```
http://[mydomain]/auth/open_id?openid_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid
```

I get connection failed error everytime

**For Yahoo**
http://[mydomain]/auth/open_id?openid_url=http%3A%2F%2Fme.yahoo.com%2F

Furthur if I try with yahoo open id , even after authenticating correctly I get invalid_credentials error
Update 1: 
  I am using apache web server, and thin/webrick app server. I verified that if I am not behind a apache web server and run directly as localhost:3000 it works fine. Why does omniauth behave differently

Comment: Seeing something similar. Did you manage to work out why this happens or how to resolve this?

Comment: @Ross you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this gem https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2, I've had good results with it.